# How to create project.framework embedded output from CocoaTouch framework project?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, carthage

I have a framework project written in swift. I want to share the framework output as xxx.framework (without source code) to 3rd parties. How can I do that in Xcode either using cocoapod / git submodules / Carthage?

Note: My framework project has both iOs and Osx targets. My framework project has other dependencies that are in both objective-c and swift

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May this [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/126365/ios-frameworks-tutorial) help you. You need to have different targets for Mac and iOS.

Comment: I already have a separate target for each os.  I just want to know how to get xxx.framework from the source code that should run in both os